# Sum of selected columns works on subset of data but not full data set

Tags: r

I have a large R data set with over 90K observations and 400 variables representing patient diagnoses. I want to calculate the sum of the values in selected columns (named Code1 through Code200) and store the value in a new column (mytotal). The code below works when I run it with a subset (around 2K) of the observations.

```
mysubset <- mysubset %>%
  mutate(mytotal = select(., Code1:Code200) %>% 
           rowSums(na.rm = TRUE))
```

However, when I try to run the same code on the full (90K observations, same dataframe structure) dataframe, I get an error:

Adding missing grouping variables: `patient_num`
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `utils = select(., Code1:Code200) %>% rowSums(na.rm = TRUE)`.
✖ `utils` must be size 1, not 92574.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: patient_num = 123456789.

I've searched online for hours to try to resolve the problem or to find an alternative solution, with no luck. If anyone has insights, I'd really appreciate them. Thank you.

Update: Just to save anyone else the hours I wasted trying to figure out the problem, it finally occurred to me to compare the subset and the full data set using class(). It turns out that the full data set had been saved as a grouped dataframe. Once I used ungroup(), the original code worked on the full data set. Apologies for the newbie distress call and thanks for the helpful responses!

Comment: Comment transcribed for @deechaz: Have you tried to identify the patient row that is causing the error? If so, what is the true limit of rows that you can perform row sums for? Do row sums work if you remove that row?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I did try excluding the row for the patient id in the error message, but I got the same error. The tidyverse approach suggested by Jon Spring (below) worked with the full data set, but I'm still not sure why my code worked with a subset of the data but not for all 90K observations. When I have some free time, I'll look into it further and I'll post an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a tidyverse approach, where we could take just the columns we want and reshape them into longer data, which will be simpler to sum.

```
set.seed(42)
df <- matrix(rnorm(9E4*400), nrow= 9E4) |> as.data.frame()

library(tidyverse)
df_sums <- df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  select(row, V1:V200) %>%
  pivot_longer(-row) %>%
  count(row, wt = value, name = "mytotal")


df %>% 
  bind_cols(df_sums)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Your suggestion worked perfectly with the full data set.